# Jquery show, hide function does not work

Tags: jquery, hide, show

Jquery find function hide and show does not work, what is wrong?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <script>
        $('div').hover(function() {
           $(this).find('.delete').show();
        }, function() {
           $(this).find('.delete').hide();
        });
  </script>


<div>
    Blah
    <span class="delete">Delete</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Code works fine for me in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/ECssL/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a document ready function to your script and it will work

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').hover(function() {
           $(this).find('.delete').show();
        }, function() {
           $(this).find('.delete').hide();
        });
      });
  </script>
```

**Explanation:**

You are binding your hover function to the div before the div even exists.
Using the document ready function, the binding of the function takes place when the div is actually available

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('div').hover(function() {
           $(this).find('.delete').show();
        }, function() {
           $(this).find('.delete').hide();
        });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your jQuery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` or `$(function(){});` to let it see the whole DOM.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('div').hover(function() {
         $(this).find('.delete').show();
     }, function() {
         $(this).find('.delete').hide();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a whole bunch of other stuff to make up a whole, valid HTML page and something wrapping the javascript to delay its execution until the document is ready to be interacted with ....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('div').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.delete').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.delete').hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    Blah
    <span class="delete">Delete</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The DOCTYPE above is for HTML5, which is probably your best bet, but you should be aware that [other DOCTYPEs are available](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

Answer (score 0):

need to wrap jQuery code like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/thinkfast2008/mzx7A/

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <div>
        Blah
        <span class="delete">Delete</span>
    </div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>




 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div').hover(function() {
               $(this).find('.delete').show();
            }, function() {
               $(this).find('.delete').hide();
            });
          });
      </script>
```